# Why can't I reach the array data by the array name in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to build a chess game in Prolog, and I started by studying this Stack Overflow post [How to access two dimensional array in prolog and how to loop each element in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55094480/how-to-access-two-dimensional-array-in-prolog-and-how-to-loop-each-element-in-it), because I think the chess game involves data of the board and pieces in a form of two dimensional array. So right now I'm trying to experiment with a simpler array to understand how it works first.

By making the most of the example code provided in the link above, I wrote a `print_array(Array)` predicate, along with the code below.

```
arraysample([[[1],[2],[3]],[[4],[5],[6]],[[7],[8],[9]]]).

array1([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]).

print_array(Array):-
    print_rows(Array).

print_rows([]):-
    write(''),nl.    % trying to create a new line before moving on to the next row, 
                     % but at this moment it's not working
print_rows([Row|Rows]):-
    print_row(Row),
    print_rows(Rows).

print_row([]).
print_row([Cell|Columns]):-
    print_cell(Cell),
    print_row(Columns).

print_cell(Cell):-
    write(Cell),
    write(' ').
```

and when I call the predicate with a hard-coded array like this, it properly prints out the array with the result `true`.

```
?- print_array([[[1],[2],[3]],[[4],[5],[6]],[[7],[8],[9]]]).
```

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] 
true.
```

But when I use the array name, it fails.

```
?- print_array(array1).
false.
```

And when I used `trace` to see what was going on, it only displayed me something like this.

```
?- trace(print_array(array1)).
%         print_array/1: [call,redo,exit,fail]
true.
```

Why does calling the predicate with an array name fail while it works with a hard-coded array? How can I get it to work with an array name as well?

**NOTE: Please provide me with some concrete examples by showing me some code when you answer my question, just like I pasted my code in my question. If you are thinking of posting an abstract comment like "Read the Prolog documentation, period.", which is not an answer for any specific question at all, don't write anything in the first place. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If you first enter `trace.`, then enter your query `print_array(array1).` separately, you'll get detailed query steps.

Comment: You're misunderstanding a fundamental aspect of Prolog. `array1([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]).` asserts a fact `array1` with argument, `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]`. `array1` is not a variable representing the value `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]`. So calling `print_array(array1)` does not subsitute `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]` for `array1` in the call. `print_array` just sees an atom, `array1` which is not a list so it fails immediately. Try, `array1(X), print_array(X).`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding a fundamental aspect of Prolog. `array1([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]).` asserts a fact `array1` with argument, `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]`. `array1` is not a variable representing the value [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]. So calling `print_array(array1)` does not subsitute `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]` for `array1` in the call. `print_array` just sees an atom, `array1` which is not a list so it fails immediately.

On the query `print_array(array1)`, Prolog attempts to unify this term with any `print_array/1` facts or heads of predicates you have. It finds `print_array(Array)` and is able to unify it with `Array = array1`.

It then calls `print_rows(array1)`. It follows the same process. However, in this case, each predicate head for `print_rows/1` involves a list:

```
print_rows([]):- ...
print_rows([Row|Rows]):- ...
```

Prolog attempts to unify the atom `array1` with `[]` and fails (try `array1 = [].` at the Prolog prompt and it will fail). It then attempts to unify `array1` with `[Row|Rows]` and fails (try `array1 = [Row|Rows].` at the Prolog prompt, and it will fail).

This the entire call `print_array(array1)` fails as there are no more alternatives.

Instead of `print_array(array1).`, do this at the Prolog prompt:

```
:- array1(Array), print_array(Array).
```

`array1(Array)` will query the `array1/1` facts and result in a solution, instantiating `Array` with `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]`. Then `print_array(Array)` will be `print_array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])`.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation :) I tried as you suggested and it went exactly as you predicted.

Comment: @Sean2014 glad you're off and running. :)